# O365 Federation Setup - Set-MsolDomainAuthentication - "Unable to complete action. Try again later" message

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, ws-federation

I'm using Powershell to convert the O365 domain to Federated using "Set-MsolDomainAuthentication" command. When I run that command with proper parameters, I get the following error - "[Set-MsolDomainAuthentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/set-msoldomainauthentication?view=azureadps-1.0) : Unable to complete this action. Try again later".

Below is the command I used -

```
cls
$dom = "mydomain.net"
$passiveLogOnUri = "{{...}}"
$activeLogOnUri = "{{...}}"
$entity = "wsfed-o365-idp"
$logOffUrl = "{{...}}"
$signingCert = "{{...}}"

Set-MsolDomainAuthentication -DomainName $dom -FederationBrandName $dom -    Authentication Federated -PassiveLogOnUri $passiveLogOnUri -SigningCertificate $signingCert -IssuerUri $entity -ActiveLogOnUri $activeLogOnUri -LogOffUri $logOffUrl -PreferredAuthenticationProtocol "WsFed"
```

I waited for a few hours and tried. I still get this error. This is getting to be a block for me. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are all these space characters between the dash and the `Authentication` parameter just typos in here or is that the actual code? With so many parameters I'd suggest you use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Sorry. That was my bad typing. When I used it in PS,  there were no unnecessary spaces.

Comment: **** RESOLVED *** 

This issue is resolved. It was an article I read in MS forums (could not find it now :( ) 
Basically, if I want to federate O365 domains with a 3rd party Identity provider, these domains cannot share the same IssueUrl. They have to unique. 

I was using the same IssuerUrI for this domain. Byt setting up another configuration and using that, I was able to make my O365 domain a federated one. 

Thanks to all who took time to review and comment. This is closed now.

Comment: @NarasimhanKidambi Add it in the answer and accept it .It will help other who have the same ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**** RESOLVED ***  It was an article I read in MS forums (could not find it now :( ) Basically if I want to federate O365 domains with a 3rd party Identity provider, these domains cannot share the same IssueUrl. They have to be unique. I was using the same IssuerUrI for this domain. Byt setting up another configuration and using that, I was able to make my O365 domain a federated one. Thanks to all who took time to review and comment.

Comment: Upvoted. In my case I got "Unable to complete this action. Try again later." error message. After changing the IssuerUri I got it working. Thanks.