# Set-MsolDomainAuthentication - “Unable to complete action. Try again later” message

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, office365, single-sign-on, ws-federation

One domain is already federated and SSO is working as expected.
I am trying to convert second office 365 domain to federated domain for SSO purpose.
Gsuite is the IDP here and Microsoft office 365 is the service provider.

But when I run "Set-MsolDomainAuthentication", I get the below error, I have also read in some article that same IssuerURI cannot be used for two different domains but Gsuite exposes only one IssuerURI.

Error:

Set-MsolDomainAuthentication : Unable to complete this action. Try again later.
At line:1 char:1

- Set-MsolDomainAuthentication -DomainName $dom -FederationBrandName $B ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Set-MsolDomainAuthentication], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.InternalServiceException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.SetDomainAuthentication
  ```

Answer (score 0):

As you already have a domain federated and if you are trying multiple domain federation with a 3rd party idp, please make sure you have  PassiveLogonUri, IssueUri, and LogoffUri unique for each mail domain, even if all users exist in a single AzureAD domain or Identity Provider. As  each mail domain you would like to federate has to federate with a unique Identity Provider URL.

It's possible to provision users and groups from more than one Azure AD tenant to a single Cloud Identity or Google Workspace account, it's currently not possible to set up single sign-on in a way that works for users across multiple Azure AD tenants. If you use multiple Azure AD tenants, you'll need to create a separate Cloud Identity or Google Workspace account for each tenant and set up federation between each pair.

Reference: [powershell - O365 Federation Setup - Set-MsolDomainAuthentication - "Unable to complete action. Try again later" message - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57397743/o365-federation-setup-set-msoldomainauthentication-unable-to-complete-actio)

[Federating Google Cloud with Azure Active Directory](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/federating-gcp-with-azure-active-directory#multiple_tenants)